# Build Docker image in privileged mode

Tags: docker, container

How to build a Docker image with privileged capabilities, like when running `docker run -ti --privileged`?

So I can mount a device while building my Dockerfile without getting an *automount* error?

Comment: any update on this question?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to build Docker images in a *privileged mode* as you do when you run a container. [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#full-container-capabilities-privileged)

`root` is already the default user when building or running your Docker container, although as you pointed out, some commands will fail, like mount a partition for example. [[2]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) [[3]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)